# Windsor IoC DefaultControllerFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am looking into Windsor for setting up an IoC container.

I went through the tutorial and it says that I have to register the WindsorControllerFactory as the DefaultControllerFactory to get things moving. The part also details that the job of this is to : 1) provide instances to the MVC runtime and 2) then to release the controller.

My questions is, doesn't the default implementation of the DefaultControllerFactory provide these tasks to provide controller instances and releasing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC's `DefaultControllerFactory` disposes the created controller, but that is not the same as releasing them. Castle Windsor will keep a reference to a created instance until you tell Windsor you are done with it. So not explicitly calling release on a controller will cause a memory leak.